# Why return a class instance inside of a class instance in Java?

Tags: java, spring, class, oop

I come from a JavaScript and [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) background, and though I have most OOP basics down, there are many Java basics that I don't quite understand. For instance, I'm doing [a Spring tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#initial) and right away came across some syntax that baffled me.

The first walkthrough is a hello world application. First, we set up a Greeting class:

```
public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

To start off with, I don't get why they define an instance of the class within the class itself. Why not just add arguments to the public class? Anyway, that's not my question. Where I get more lost is when we make a Greeting controller:

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    // This ensures that HTTP requests to /greeting are mapped to the greeting() method.
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

In this file, I sort of get that `public Greeting greeting` creates a new instance of the Greeting class, but it only has one argument when the constructor has two, `long id` and `String content`. Next, they return another instance of the class, this time with arguments that match the constructor's structure.

Why is this?

Comment: _define an instance of the class within the class itself_ Where do you see that? Also, if that's not your question or relevant to it, remove it.

Comment: _`public Greeting greeting` creates a new instance of the Greeting class_ No, it doesn't. It's just a method with a return type of `Greeting`.

Comment: "but it only has one argument when the constructor has two" - isn't the other argument "String.format(...)"? (Looks like a comma is being used instead of a dot on that line too?)

Comment: And what do you mean by "add arguments to the public class"? A class doesn't have arguments... a method or constructor call does. If you're really new to Java, I'd *strongly* urge you to drop the Spring side of things to start with, and learn the basics of the language first.

Comment: You should really learn Java before you go into an advanced framework like Spring MVC.

Comment: Don't do a Spring tutorial right away. You'll want to learn the Java basics first, otherwise you'll be confused every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I recommend you to learn the Java programming language, without Spring:

- *[The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)*
- *[Java tutorial for beginners with examples](http://beginnersbook.com/java-tutorial-for-beginners-with-examples/)*

With

```
public class Greeting {
```

you're defining a class with name Greeting. That's your class.

Inside this class you have:

```
public Greeting(long id, String content) {
```

This is the constructor of the class. In Java there aren't objects without calling their constructor. So in order to create a new object you have to call its constructor.

Then you have

```
public class GreetingController {
```

This defines another class, in this case GreetingController.

This class has a method (function):

```
 public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name)
```

This method receives a string called `name` and returns an object (instance) of Greeting. In order to return the instance of Greeting you have to create the instance first and this is made calling its constructor:

```
return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
            String.format(template, name));
```

This line is calling the constructor and passing two parameters, the same that you defined before in the Greeting class' constructor.

Answer (score 2):

When to use chaining

The function sequence is often common with languages where IDE with autocomplete is a common place. For example, most Visual C # developers use Visual Studio. Therefore, if you are developing with C #, adding a sequence to your methods can be a time saver for users of that row because Visual Studio will help you create the string.

On the other hand, you will see languages such as PHP of a very dynamic nature and often do not have autocomplete support in the IDEs. The sequence will only be appropriate when using the correct phpDocs to expose sequential methods.

What is chaining?

Given a class named Foo the following two methods are both chainable.

```
function what() { return this; }
function when() { return new Foo(this); }
```

The fact that one is a reference to the current instance, and one creates a new instance does not alter that these are sequential methods.

There is no golden rule that the sequential method should refer only to the current object. Sequential and contiguous roads can be across two different categories. For example,

```
class B { function When() { return true; } };
class A { function What() { return new B(); } };

var a = new A();
var x = a.What().When();
```

There is no reference to this in any of the example above. The code is a.What (). When () is an example of a sequence. Interestingly, class B is never assigned to a variable.

The method is restricted when the return value is used as a later component of the expression.

Here are some more example

// return value never assigned.

```
 myFile.Open("something.txt").Write("stuff").Close();
```

// two chains used in expression

```
int x = a.X().Y() * b.X().Y();
```

// a chain that creates new strings

```
string name = str.Substring(1,10).Trim().ToUpperCase();
```

When to use this and new(this)

The strings in most languages are not changeable. Sequential method calls always create new strings. Where an object such as StringBuilder can be modified.

Consistency is best practice.

If you have methods that modify the state of the object and return this, do not confuse the methods that return the new instances. Instead, create a specific method called Clone () that will do so explicitly.

```
 var x  = a.Foo().Boo().Clone().Foo();
```

This is more obvious to what is going on inside.
Step out and trick back

I call this step backward because it solves many common problems with serialization. It basically means that you graduate from the original class into a new temporary class and then return to the original semester.

There is no temporary category except to provide special features for the original category, but only under special circumstances.

There are often times when the series needs to change the situation, but Class A can not represent all of these potential situations. Therefore, during a string, a new class that contains a reference is presented to A. This allows the programmer to enter the status and return to A.

Here is ideal, let the special state know b.

```
class A {
    function Foo() { return this; }
    function Boo() { return this; }
    function Change() return new B(this); }
}

class B {
    var _a;
    function (A) { _a = A; }
    function What() { return this; }
    function When() { return this; }
    function End() { return _a; }
}

    var a = new A();
    a.Foo().Change().What().When().End().Boo();
```

Now that is a very simple example. If you wanted to have more control, then B could return to a new super-type of A that has different methods.

I also recommend you too hackr community to get the best java tutorials: https://hackr.io/tutorials/learn-java

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you're question, but I try to give you an answer.

Normaly you use a Controller (in you're case a GreetengsController) to expose a resource to the world. This resource is a Greeting object/instance. You initialise the object with two arguments (in you're case a long and a String).

The

```
public Greeting greeting(... String name)
```

is a method (function) declaration that says: this fuctionn expect a String "name" as parameter and returns an object Greeting to the client (caller), and with

```
return new Greeting(....)
```

you return the Greeting object. Normally you make a litle bit more with the objects (not only return a new instance)

I don't know if I answered you're question. If not. Please tell me.

Answer (score -1):

*public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name)* only defines a method *greeting* with return type *Greeting*

```
new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
        String.format(template, name))
```

The above code actually created a new instance of Greeting and returned it.